# Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, oledb, linked-server

Getting the following error in SQL Server 2008 when trying to select data from an Excel (xls) file:

```
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 43
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server
```

The SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;Database=c:\\Temp\\Book1.xls;', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

Steps taken:

1. Installed the Access Database Engine. 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' **does** show up in Server Objects > Linked Servers > Providers
2. Made sure 'Dynamic parameters' and 'Allow inprocess' is selected
3. Made sure the Excel file was closed
4. Made sure 'ad hoc distributed queries' was enabled (1)
5. Made sure the user running the SQL service has permissions to the c:\temp\ folder

My theory:
Running on my dev box works fine as my SQL service is running as 'LocalSystem'. The target server I'm trying to get running has a specific network user it's running on. This cannot be changed.

From what I know/have read about OPENROWSET and OPENQUERY (also tried with linked server) it needs to create a temporary file in C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\\AppData\Local\Temp. I've manually tried to create a folder structure for this user in service profiles but that doesn't work either.

:: UPDATE ::
In the end I abandoned this idea and instead created an package in integration services. As this process needs to run as part of a job this works well enough for my needs.

If anyone is interested. Creating the package in IS is as easy as following the import data wizard and at the end you choose 'Create Integrated Services Package'. This can then be called from your job.
Ta

Comment: This worked fine for me. I removed the double `\\`, only used 1.

Comment: Does the service user in question have permissions to the folder? Simply creating the folder does not give a user rights unless they are inherited.

Comment: Yes the user was given permissions to the folder as per item 4.)

Comment: Did you set this EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql

Comment: Are you sure Sheet1$ exists? And it wasn't renamed in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Yup Sheet1 exists. Yes distributed queries = 1 (I'll update the question with that info)

Comment: What is the target SQL Server service account permission? if not sysadmin, does it have 'ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS' permission?

Comment: You do know that the c:\ is referncing the c:\ on the server and not any workstaion's c:\ don't you?

Comment: @Ciarán - yep I do. All paths were correct. I was even remoted into the server. This will just have to be one of lifes little mysteries..